# XSLT sum results for template

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML document which consists of two basic elements:

- Health Centers.
- Activities.

Each Health Center and Activity contains member identification.

**XML**

```
<root>
   <centers>
      <center>
         <name>Santa Clara</name>
         <members>
            <member id="1000020001"/>
            <member id="1000020002"/>
            <member id="1000020005"/>
         </members>
      </center>
      <center>
         <name>San Jose</name>
         <members>
            <member id="1000020003"/>        
         </members>
      </center>
      <center>
         <name>Sunnyvale</name>
         <members>
            <member id="1000020004"/>        
         </members>
      </center>
   </centers>   
   <activities>
      <activity name="yoga" start="2016-10-12" end="2016-12-17">
         <members>
            <member id="1000020001"/>
         </members>
      </activity>
      <activity name="spinning" start="2017-10-12" end="2017-12-17">
         <members>
            <member id="1000020001"/>
            <member id="1000020002"/>
         </members>
      </activity>
      <activity name="box" start="2017-10-12" end="2017-12-17">
         <members>           
            <member id="1000020003"/>
         </members>
      </activity>
      <activity name="bachata" start="2017-10-12" end="2017-12-17">
         <members>           
            <member id="1000020004"/>
         </members>
      </activity>
   </activities>
</root>
```

Im using a second XML document which can handle rules to get more information for these health centers:

**Rules XML**

```
<Evaluation>
    <query score="0.25">
        <rules>
            <rule>yoga</rule>
            <rule>spinning</rule>
        </rules>        
    </query>
    <query score="1">
        <rules>
            <rule>box</rule>             
        </rules>        
    </query>   
</Evaluation>
```

I need to use this XML to score Health centers which matches my activities:

Example:

- Santa Clara score: 0.75 (1 member in Yoga (0.25 * 1) + 2 members in Spinning (0.25 * 2))
- San Jose score: 1 ( 1 member in Box (1.0 * 1)
- Sunnyvale score: 0

Im creating the XSL below, but due to the nature of XSL functional behavior I can't add up in the loop and return value to add up again per member.

**Questions:**

a) I'm not able to loop over each member and add up the result for all members in center.

b) When query has multiple interests (yoga and spinning) how to use xpath to match more than 1 rule. Right now I'm using this:

```
$Evaluation/Evaluation/query/rules/rule[text()=$rule_name]
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!-- use key to extract node information -->    
    <xsl:key name="activity-key" match="activity" use="members/member/@id" />
    <xsl:variable name="Evaluation" select=" document('Evaluation.xml')"/>

    <!-- match root document -->
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <!-- process each center in document -->
        <xsl:for-each select="centers/center">                           
            <!-- create reference per center: --> 
            <b><xsl:value-of select="center-name"/></b>
            <xsl:for-each select="members/member">
                member: <xsl:value-of select="@id" />              
                <xsl:for-each select="key('activity-key', @id)">
                    -activity: <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                    <xsl:call-template name="calculate">
                        <xsl:with-param name="rule_name" select="@name"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <div/>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <div/>
            </xsl:for-each>  
            <div/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="calculate">
        <xsl:param name="rule_name"/>         
        <xsl:variable name="match_rule" select="$EvaluationML/EvaluationML/query/rules/rule[text()=$rule_name]"/>        
        <xsl:variable name="matches" select="count($match_interest)"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$Evaluation/Evaluation/query">            
            <xsl:variable name="query_score" select="@score"/>
            score: <b> <xsl:value-of select="$query_score * $matches"/></b>            
        </xsl:for-each>        
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is the expected result (as code) of transforming the given example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you try this as your starting point:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="rules" select="'Rules.xml'"/>

<xsl:key name="activities" match="activity" use="members/member/@id" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="centers/center"> 
            <xsl:variable name="member-ids" select="members/member/@id" />
            <xsl:variable name="points">
                <xsl:for-each select="key('activities', $member-ids)">  
                    <xsl:variable name="score" select="document($rules)/Evaluation/query[rules/rule=current()/@name]/@score" />
                    <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(members/member[@id=$member-ids])" />
                    <value>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$score">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$score * $count"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>       
                    </value>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <h3>
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            </h3>
            <p>Score: <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($points)/value)"/></p>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </body>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input (after closing properly the `members` elements!), the result will be:

```
<body>
   <h3>Santa Clara</h3>
   <p>Score: 0.75</p>
   <h3>San Jose</h3>
   <p>Score: 1</p>
   <h3>Sunnyvale</h3>
   <p>Score: 0</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Michael, thanks again for your help, it worked perfectly.